# `psql` expanded mode equivalency for `mysql`

Tags: mysql, postgresql, psql, echo, command-line-interface

Am frustated by things like:

```
0:33:1407402356:root@ahost:~# echo 'use wordpress_3_6_1; select * from wp_posts;'
 | mysql -u mysqluser -pmysqlpasswdord | wc -l -L
42   40585
```

SQL query results being mangled ugly.

PostgreSQL s `psql` provides the helper feature *expanded mode*. See it in action:

```
postgres@ahost:~$ echo '\c openerp7-0 \\ select * from pg_shadow' | psql
You are now connected to database "openerp7-0" as user "postgres".
 usename  | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd | userepl |          
   passwd                | valuntil | useconfig 
----------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+---------+----------
-------------------------+----------+-----------
 openerp |    16384 | t           | t        | t         | t       | 
ahash |          | 
 postgres |       10 | t           | t        | t         | t       | 
anotherhash |          | 
(2 rows)

postgres@ahost:~$ echo '\c openerp7-0 \\ \x \\ select * from pg_shadow' |
psql                
You are now connected to database "openerp7-0" as user "postgres".
Expanded display is on.
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------
usename     | openerp
usesysid    | 16384
usecreatedb | t
usesuper    | t
usecatupd   | t
userepl     | t
passwd      | ahash
valuntil    | 
useconfig   | 
-[ RECORD 2 ]------------------------------------
usename     | postgres
usesysid    | 10
usecreatedb | t
usesuper    | t
usecatupd   | t
userepl     | t
passwd      | anotherhash
valuntil    | 
useconfig   |
```

That expanded mode is cute for tables with *many* columns:

```
postgres@ahost:~$ echo '\c openerp7-0 \\ \x \\ select * from res_partner' |
psql | wc -l -L
223   44423
postgres@ahost:~$ echo '\c openerp7-0 \\ select * from res_partner' | psql |
wc -l -L
  9   94030
```

Of course that is only when people do not mind mangling up the row count with `wc -l`.

How can people accomplish for `mysql` a feature similar to the expanded mode featured in `psql`?

Comment: Now am in the need of something like expanded mode, for Oracle `sqlplus`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you can try it with the \G separator (instead of semicolon), like this:

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM mytable\G' | mysql -u myuser -p mypassword mydb
```

Example output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
    id: 1
locale: de
  name: Afghanistan
*************************** 2. row ***************************
    id: 2
locale: de
  name: Ägypten
```

Comment: Nice. Obviating the obvious and obviously obviable horizontal aligning difference, it will make OK for me in most cases.

Comment: So in `man mysql` they call it the _vertical format_. But it is related to an _ego_ command, that does the same as _go_ but displaying results using the vertical format. Maybe that _e_ in _ego_ stands for _expanded_. Guess the terminology comes from earlier closed source RDBMS most notably Oracle.